# pip install django~=1.11.0 command = AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'

Tags: django, windows, windows-7, pip, installation

I am trying to install Django after pip upgrade through command:

```
pyhton -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, when I run this command:

```
pip install django~=1.11.0
```

I get tons of errors :

```
AttributeError : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

Anyone with the quick solution?

Comment: `pip install django=1.11.0`.

Comment: Do i have to do all the steps all over again? cuz it doesnot work with your solution too.

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Comment: Windows 7. Still stuck in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following: (notice 2 equal signs)

```
pip install django==1.11
```